# JSONP request not working showing error 404

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I am trying to load some data from whois.com but the request is failing with 404 not found. In the past it was working but not sure why it stops now. it is a small java script function to find Domain Age.

URL - mygovjobs.in/tools Code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var domainCheckerUrl = "http://www.whois.com/whois/google.com";

   /*This line is giving error */ $.getJSON("http://alloworigin.com/get?url=" + encodeURIComponent(domainCheckerUrl) + "&callback=?", function(data){

          $('#urlname')[0].value = "";
          var dataElement =  $(data.contents).find('#registryData')[0];
```

Comment: What happens when you try to access this URL directly?

Comment: this is the second question like this I've seen in the last 24 hours - I think it should be `anyorigin.com` not `alloworigin.com`

Comment: oh, I see ... same person asked the same question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39928494/jsonp-request-showing-error-404-not-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namaste **Mahesh**,
from the site, it looks like the server is not fully functional yet, some configurations are missing! Maybe that's the reason you are getting `404`.

have a look at the snapshot of `alloworigin.com`.
[image]